# Centering 1-digit, 2-digit and 3-digit page numbers to the same place

Tags: horizontal-alignment, page-numbering, fancyhdr, center

I currently write my page numbers with `fancyhdr` via:

```
\fancyfoot[RO]{\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}%
              \begin{picture}(0,0)
                \put(1.6cm,-1cm){\Large{\thepage}}
                \end{picture}}%
\fancyfoot[LE]{\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}%
              \begin{picture}(0,0)
                \put(-1.6cm,-1cm){\Large{\thepage}}
                \end{picture}}%
```

At the moment the center of the page number changes depending on whether it's a 1-digit, 2-digit and 3-digit page number. How can I make it have the same center every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a zero width box; I used asymmetric placement, decide what you prefer by acting on the positioning argument to `\makebox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[RO]{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(1.6cm,-1cm){\makebox[0pt][r]{\Large\thepage}}
  \end{picture}}%
\fancyfoot[LE]{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-1.6cm,-1cm){\makebox[0pt][l]{\Large\thepage}}
  \end{picture}}%
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{7}

\kant[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you use explicit lengths in `\put`, you don't need to set `\unitlength`. Also, `\Large` does not take an argument.